# Destination Entities are not appearing in CRM SSIS Destination Editor

Tags: ssis-2012, data-migration, dynamics-crm-2016, kingswaysoft

I am using `Kinswaysoft` to migrate data from OLE DB to Dynamics CRM (on-premise). Now in CRM destination editor, the `Destination Entity` is empty and it throw below error:

> Failed to retrieve CRM entities. KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCRM.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: An error has occured when retrieving CRM entity metadata: CRM service call returned an error: An unexpected error occured. (Error Code: -2147220970, Detail Message: An unexpected error occured)(Error Code: -2147220970, Detail Message: An unexpected error occured)(SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, V11.0.0.7160)

In connection manager the connection with CRM was successful and still I can browse the CRM using the same username and password. Still not able to figure out the issue.

I need your expert opinion to get the list of entities in Destination Entity list.

**UPDATE**
Below is the screenshot of the issue;
[image]

Comment: There is a problem with the server based on the error message, the best way is to turn on CRM trace log and find out the details. We communicated on Facebook yesterday, I was giving the same suggestion. Were you able to find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Which endpoint are you using? I know that Kingswaysoft still view the WebAPI endpoint to be a bit "preview" as it doesn't support all features of the platform. I personally still use the SOAP 2011 endpoint until they tell me otherwise. I have never had that problem.